# Some of our users press enter a few times which count as logon attempts

Tags: windows, security, login, login-screen

We don't allow empty password so it should not count as a logon attempt.

However, some of our users press enter a few times to "wake up" the computer in the morning which results in them getting locked out.

Can I let Windows ignore this empty password submissions? (We use Active Directory and Citrix)

Thanks!

Comment: What OS do you use? Maybe you can set CTRL+ALT+DEL to be pressed before they can type their password?

Comment: Retrain them to use the space bar instead?

Comment: This is really more of a customer education issue than a technical issue.  If they are determined to "button mash" in an attempt to revive the computer, we teach our end-users to utilize the **Esc** key, instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do about it however, what you can alternatively do which is not recommended is not to ask for a password when the computer wakes up, or you can increase the account lockout threshold by 2 - 3 times before it locks the computer depending on your security needs which is a better solution .

Answer (score 0):

This is why the standard security procedure is to require CTRL-ALT-DEL before the authentication boxes are visible.

Any key (or key combo) will serve to wake the computer, but keys (even ENTER) pressed before CTRL-ALT-DEL is pressed will not trigger a login attempt.